# Active Directory: Searching Users/Group in LDAP via C++

Tags: c++, ldap

Currently we started to migrate our existing authentication to Active Directory authetication,
but now i am facing lot of issues in searching users and group.

let me explain you we have an application/server who will autheticate and authorize user. so we will change our server to autheticate from LDAP server configured.

i know we should have service account, so i have ldap setup and service account exist.

1. How to search user with password via service account
2. How to search group
3. How to search user is part of group

it would be good if someone refer any book and code sample to understand the LDAP search functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP: Programming Directory-Enabled Apps by Mark Smith, Timothy A. Howes

This book contains lot of code samples using C. I have not looked at other books though. This was sufficient for me to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Matt Butcher, *Mastering OpenLDAP,* PackT Publishing 2007, ISBN 978-1-847191-02-1.